# keeping GET variables after URL rewrite

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url

im trying to rewrite my product page URLs which are dynamic

an example of one is:

```
product.php?id=780-1AC930D
```

and Im trying to rewrite it to:

product/780-1AC930D

i need the variable to still pass through with the URL though but currently its not working for me.

I have a redirect at the top of the `product.php` page something like this:

```
$prodID = $_GET['id'];
    if(!isset($prodID) && $prodId == ""){
        header( 'Location: http://www.***********.com' ) ;
    }       
    else{
```

and I know the GET variable isnt passing through because it keeps redirecting me.

the code I have for the HTACCESS file is this:

```
 Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$ /product.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

and the HTML for the URL is:

```
<a href = "product/<?php echo $product[$i]['catID'];?>">
```

does anybody have a clue why this isnt working?

EDIT to give more information.

This is my entire HTACCESS file

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 

RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$ /product.php?id=$1 [QSA]

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]

## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]

## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l

## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?cat=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^.]+)\.php\?cat=([^\s&]+)&subCat=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?cat=$2&subCat=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^.]+)\.php\?cat=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]


# REMOVE PHP EXTENSIONS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

I just moved `RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$ /product.php?id=$1 [QSA]` from above the "# REMOVE PHP EXTENSIONS" to below the RewriteBase and it appears to fix my problem.

The other rewrite rules are for my category and sub category pages before you actually make it to a product page.

So im curious as to why placing this product.php line above this other stuff has done it?

Comment: Have you done any debugged already? What is the error message?

Comment: I dont receive error messages. it just redirects me because of the IF statement which states if $_GET['id'] doesnt exist then redirect. If I take that redirect out then it just loads a blank product page

Comment: Just to rule out typos, caching of redirects, and such, what do you see with `var_dump($_GET)`?

Comment: var_dump($_GET); gives me "array(1) { ["cat"]=> string(11) "780-1AC930D" }" But var_dump($_GET['id']); gives me "NULL"

Comment: That implies your rewrite rules aren't what you have pasted above...

Comment: well I have others for other pages...but that is the one for the product page

Comment: The problem is that your rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$ /product.php?id=$1` is actually `RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$ /product.php?cat=$1`. Perhaps you have an error in one of your other rewrite rules that is causing this as opposed to this one specifically.

Comment: @Kevlar: Can you post your complete .htaccess? I suspect some rule is hijacking this rule.

Comment: ok ive edited my question to show it

Comment: Comment this line and try again `RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?cat=$2 [L,QSA]`

Comment: that causes internal server error when navigating through the categories to a product page

Comment: Try changing the rewrite flags to `[QSA,L]` - that will end the rewrite list with that rule then and no further processing will take place. Incidentally, what is `$prdId` (with the lower-case 'd') ? And your `!isset($prodID)` will generate an error level of `Notice` if `$_GET['id']` isn't set. You'd be better off with something like `$prdID = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;` and then evaluating that with `is_null($prdID)` in the if statement...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that an other rule matched the request, before the rule you wanted to match. In this case the rule that matched your request was:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?cat=$2 [L,QSA]
```

The L-flag will stop rewriting for this cycle. It therefore never reached

```
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)$ /product.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

See [this documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html) for information about flags and [this documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more information about mod_rewrite in general.

Comment: This rule shouldn't be executed since `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]` rule is there before it.

Comment: this makes sense and would explain why moving it to the top fixed it

Comment: @anubhava That condition is for `RewriteRule ^ - [L]`. Also `product/asdf` is most likely not a file, just a fancy url. @Kevlar It matches and executes rules from the top to the bottom, and will go through `.htaccess` until the url doesn't change anymore.

Comment: True but it comes `/product.php?id=asdf` and that is actually a file.

Comment: @anubhava `/product.php?cat=asdf` (which it became) will not match `^product/(.*)$` anyway, so even if OP would remove that rule, it would not fix the problem. OP expected the `product` rule to be matched and executed, but it would never reach that rule due to a conflicting rule. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` played no part in it, not before OP moved the `product` rule and not after he moved it and exactly the same thing would have happened if OP removed that rule.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely problem is **not using** `L` flag in your first rule. Have it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^product/(.+)$ /product.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: changed my flag to your suggestion. with that line still at the top everything is working ok right now thanks

Comment: Good to know. It is better to keep `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]` rule always at the top so that you can avoid accidents like this even after adding new rules.